# How to disable cache for app.user

Tags: symfony, caching

I have a Symfony2 page that I want to cache:

```
$response = $this->render(...);
$response->setMaxAge(15*60);
return $response;
```

Now on that page I am showing the `username` (if logged in) or the login button if not logged in. Now when that page is called and I'm logged, logout and go back to that page, the `username` is still displayed.

How can I prevent this behaviour while still having cache enabled for the body of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best accomplished using ESI.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-esi-in-symfony

You can cache parts of a page separately with ESI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know a less invasive approach?

Comment: You can try to simply use the render tag in Twig and embed a controller response which in turn has cache rules.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers